# Djangothumbnails app issue

Tags: django, django-models

I an using [this plugin to](http://djangothumbnails.com/) generate thumbnails. But somhow I couldn't make it work. The models work well, as images can be uploaded from the admin interface, even thumbnails get generated. I uploaded an image named "myphoto.jpg". The view I have is this.

```
def mainpage(request,slug):
    page = get_object_or_404(MainPage, slug=slug)
    image = get_object_or_404(Image)
    return direct_to_template(request, 'flatpage.html',
        extra_context={
            'page':page,
            'image':image,
        })
```

I have defined the class in models as "Image". I had this in the template:
`<img src="{% image.photo.myphoto_125x125 %}">` But the template shows error.

This is my model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='images/', sizes=((125,125),(200,200)))
    # second_photo = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to='site_media/images')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The second field, "second_photo" I have commented out as it created duplicate copy of the main image. Even I am looking for a way to create entry for actual unsized image in the first field itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got it working. Instead of creating a separate class, I used this line `photo = ImageWithThumbsField(blank=True, upload_to='images/', sizes=((125,125),(200,200)))` in my [blog class](http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/defining-your-models.html). And I used the line `{{% post.photo.url_125x124 %}` in my `index.html` template.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this app, but I am using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to create thumbnail versions of uploaded images, and using a def in the model to retrieve the path to the thumbnail for display.   This may be more of a manual approach than you are looking for but it works ok for me.  You can override the save method on your model (which has your FileField) or send a post_save [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) to a def to create the thumbnail.

But curious to know if this app you are using adds some useful functionality over this manual approach.